# De "unsigned char" a Decimal mediante printf

Tags: c, ccs, pic

tengo el siguiente código por el cual me conecto a un sensor y recibo datos del mismo que los guardo en variables tipo "unsigned char"

```
    #include <18f2550.h>
    #fuses   HSPLL,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP,NODEBUG,USBDIV,PLL5,CPUDIV1,VREGEN
    #USE     delay(clock=48000000)
    #use i2c(Master,Fast,sda=PIN_B0,scl=PIN_B1)

    #include <usb_cdc.h>


 void main() {

 i2c_start();
 i2c_write(0x54);
 i2c_write(0x00);
 i2c_write(0x83);
 i2c_write(0x54);
 i2c_write(0x00);
 i2c_write(0x03);
 i2c_stop();

 usb_cdc_init();
 usb_init();

       while(TRUE) {

           delay_ms(720);
           i2c_write(0x54);
           i2c_write(0x03);
           i2c_write(0x55);

           unsigned char RM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char RL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char GM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char GL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char BM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char BL=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char IM=i2c_read(1);
           unsigned char IL=i2c_read(0);
           i2c_stop();

           usb_task();


               if (usb_enumerated()) {


                     printf(usb_cdc_putc,"%d",RM);
                     printf(usb_cdc_putc,"%d",RL);                        
                     printf(usb_cdc_putc, "\f ");

               }

       }

   }
```

RM son los 8 bits mas significativos del dato y RL los menos significativos. Me gustaría saber como expresar este dato como un total en Decimal mediante el comando "printf".

Por ejemplo si me llegara el dato RM=11111111 y RL=11111111 que se presentara en la pantalla como 65535.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La conversión de `char` a `int` es **implicita**; C internamente **siempre** trabaja con datos de tamaño `int` como mínimo.

Por lo tanto, solo tienes que hacer un `or` binario entre tus datos:

```
printf( "%d", (dato << 8) | dato2 );
```

Aquí entra en juego el ENDIAN, así que, si no te da el resultado esperado, simplemente *intercambia* tus datos:

```
printf( "%d", (dato2 << 8) | dato );
```

Observa que uso `"%d"`. Esto es así por como trabaja C con los números **sin signo**; si intentas usar `"%u"`, verás un resultado ... *curioso* ;-)

Comment: parece expresar bien el dato en decimal aunque creo que lo que ahora falla (o eso supongo) es la comunicación I2C. Sabrías corregir cualquier error de mi comunicación i2C con mi sensor?

Muchas gracias de todas formas porque la duda principal está resuelta :D

Comment: No he usado I2C ... y puede ser un problema específico de ese sensor, así que no puede serte de mucha ayuda con eso :-(

Comment: Hola @Alberto, bienvenido a SOes. Si consideras que esta respuesta ha sido correcta, deberías marcarla como tal, ya que ha solucionado tu problema (esto ayudará tanto a quien ha respondido como al que tenga la misma duda). Si te surge otro problema, deberías hacer otra pregunta a parte.

Comment: Muchas gracias Trauma :)